# Distributing LWJGL game

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl

I have a project at school , game in browser .I have the game (made in java with LWJGL) and now I`m trying to make it an online game.I tried with an applet but I get countless errors
first error

```
RuneTimeException : LWJGL classnotfounderror
```

I tried to fix thix problem but didn't work

Now I`ve tried with appletLoader from lwhgl_util_applet but I`m getting the error:

```
An error occurred while loading the applet.Please contact support to resolve this issue.This occurred while 'Determining packages to load.
```

So I`ve tried 2 days to make an online game using applet , got other solution but applet?

Comment: You can try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html, But I've had a shitload of trouble with LWJGL Applets as well. I gave up because I can't find my exact problem anywhere. I tried applet loader and jnlp it remains a mystery to as to why.
PM me if you ever get it to work.

Comment: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/test/applet/GearsApplet.java

My applet is working now :),I`m using lwjgl_applet_loader and that link really helped me.Also I do not know why but is now working with java 7.45 so control panel-> java advance and unchecked enable last generation of java ( or something like that).

Comment: I am glad it helped, Now if you could help me in return that would be nice.
Could I get a copy of your html/php? and the jnlp's if you are using any?
And also could you tell me how your map structure is organized?
I suggest posting this on this question as answer own question.
I am trying to make an extensive tutorial.
Also could you upvote my helping comment, that would help me, help others c;

Comment: need 15 reputation to vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head><title>applet</title></head>

<body>

    <applet code=org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.class
        archive=lwjgl_util_applet.jar
        codebase="."
        width="640" height="480">

        <param name="al_title" value="Mad race">

        <param name="al_main" value="Tanc.Game">

        <param name="al_jars" value= "lwjgl.jar ,final.jar,slick.jar">

        <param name="al_logo" value="appletlogo.gif">

        <param name="al_progressbar" value="appletprogress.gif">

        <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar">
    </applet>

    <a href="http://java.com/en/download/help/new_plugin.xml"><p><b>Note </b>
    Din cauza unor probleme de securitate de la sun/java ,applet-ul ruleaza pe java 
    < 7.45 </p></a><br>
    <p> De asemenea trebuie sa aveti instalata ultima veriune a driver-elor ,deoarce este necesar openGL4+</p>

</body>
```

and I have all jars in same folder/dir with the html file.
Also you jave to sign your jar( mine is final.jar ) see youtobe how to sign jars and on java 7.45 I have some security problems so I go CP-> java - > security = medium and advanced = uncheck enable last generation of java plug-in.Lunch with IE.

IF you have more questions please comment I will respond as soon as possible .